# How to get rid of source-map-support TypeError: frame.getFileName is not a function in node 10

Tags: node.js, angular, protractor

I just upgraded from `node 8` to `node 10` and all my protractor test cases failed.

When dig into it, I found that source map support is causing the issue. Anyone resolved it or have a workaround.

```
✗ encountered a declaration exception
  - TypeError: frame.getFileName is not a function
      at isInsideNodeModules (internal/util.js:360:28)
      at showFlaggedDeprecation (buffer.js:149:8)
      at new Buffer (buffer.js:174:3)
      at Array.<anonymous> (/Users/k26686/aniruddh/develop/after-india-trip/shepherd/node_modules/source-map-support/source-map-support.js:149:21)
      at /Users/k26686/aniruddh/develop/after-india-trip/shepherd/node_modules/source-map-support/source-map-support.js:53:24
      at mapSourcePosition (/Users/k26686/aniruddh/develop/after-india-trip/shepherd/node_modules/source-map-support/source-map-support.js:171:21)
      at wrapCallSite (/Users/k26686/aniruddh/develop/after-india-trip/shepherd/node_modules/source-map-support/source-map-support.js:343:20)
      at /Users/k26686/aniruddh/develop/after-india-trip/shepherd/node_modules/source-map-support/source-map-support.js:378:26
      at Array.map (<anonymous>)
      at Function.prepareStackTrace (/Users/k26686/aniruddh/develop/after-india-trip/shepherd/node_modules/source-map-support/source-map-support.js:377:24)
```

There is also a issue in github [github isslue link](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/20258) going on but any one have a quick fix?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just have to upgrade to version 10.1.0 of NodeJS.

This is a bug in version 10.0.0.

Answer (score 1):

We found a workaround if using Babel to compile code. Switching your source maps from inline to file fixed this for us.

Change Babel compilation from:

> babel --source-maps **inline**

to

> babel --source-maps

Comment: I am not using babel. I am only using angular cli which internally uses web pack.

Comment: @AniruddhaDas try changing your webpack devtool to be not inline https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/

Answer (score 0):

Incase you are a homebrew user, run this command to update node to latest version:

```
brew upgrade node
```

This will update node to latest version. This issue is fixed in latest version.